# How to Create Android Emulator like iPhone X (asus zenfone 5 , nova 3e)

Tags: android, android-emulator, iphone-x

I'm facing some problem with some Android devices which is likely iPhone X (ex: Asus zenfone 5, Nova 3e). I already working on it now I need to test them.

As I don't have any real device right now is it possible to build an emulator like those in the android studio? If **Yes** then how can I? and if **No** than what you prefer?

Comment: Have you tried genymotion?

Comment: Download the android P emulator and from the developer option, enable the notch.

Comment: Sorry, @Abhishek. I didn't try it. Actually, I want to be sure it'll work because I don't like genymotion really.
and SandipSoni thanks for the suggestion. I'm gonna try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test application notch display, here ([How to set notch on android emulator](https://medium.com/@hiteshdhamshaniya.wvmagic/notch-android-emulator-with-p-e9b3556d9d5e)) I describe step to get notch on android p emulators

Answer (score -1):

Try [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). You will have to create an account in order to use it. For testing purposes for a limited time, you can work a demo/trial account. Genymotion supports almost every Android device.